# How to check if jQuery Validation Engine is loaded?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I'm trying to use this validator: http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/
I load it just when a page has a form. But I have several pages with 2 form, both are loading with ajax. So, I need to check for each form before load: is the Validator loaded or not. how can I to check this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

You can check for the existence of `$.validator`:

```
if ($.validator) {
    // $.validator is defined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin adds a `validationPlugin` function to `jQuery.fn`, so simply check whether it exists or not;

```
if (typeof jQuery.fn.validationPlugin === "function") {
    // It's loaded
} else {
    // It's not.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with ValidationEngine 2.6.2:

```
if (typeof jQuery.fn.validationEngine === "function") {
    // It's loaded
} else {
    // It's not.
}
```